# No test is available in dll, Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform & framework version

Tags: mstest, azure-pipelines

I am trying to run a test from azureDevop pipeline and I am getting the error:

**Warning: No test is available in D:\data\CHT.....\myTest.dll. Make sure that installed test discoverers & executors, platform & framework version settings are appropriate and try again**

Those are the nugets I use in myTest project:
[image]

This is what I have in the output directory:

[image]

In myTest.cs file I have a test method:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void ValidateLoading()
    {
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(urlToTest);
    }
```

I can run it locally in VS. Only when this checkbox is disable (in tools->options):

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: can you share your pipeline?

Comment: I can't, sorry. It's not app to me. Do you think this is something in the pipeline? What could it be? I can check the things you wanted to see and will tell you

Comment: It could be, check the test task if the configuration is correct.

Comment: I am using cloudtest task. Which configuration is matter? It's seems that it recognize the dll file but can't run it. I thought that maybe some nugets are missing? Or some configurations in my project code